# Cloud Functions: How to handle .then() for task accomplished or not accomplished?

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying update the `status` value in the node `.child("Merchans").child(userId).child(merchanId)` if there is a node in `ref` to be removed.

But the returned promise of `remove().then()`is always **undefined** either when the node exists or not.

```
exports.cancelAnnouncements = functions.database
.ref('Cancelads/{userId}')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
  const userId = context.params.userId;

  const targetCountry = snapshot.val().country;
  const targetState = snapshot.val().state;
  const startTime = snapshot.val().ini;
  const merchanId = snapshot.val().merchanId;
  const status = snapshot.val().status;

  var ref;
  if (status === 1) {
    const targetRegion = getTargetRegion(targetCountry, targetState);
    ref = admin.database().ref()
    .child('Queue')
    .child(targetRegion)
    .child(startTime.toString())
    .child(merchanId);

    console.log("inside queue");
  } else if (status === 2) {
    ref = admin.database().ref()
    .child('Announcements')
    .child(targetCountry)
    .child(targetState)
    .child(merchanId);

    console.log("inside announcements");
  }

  return ref.remove().then((result) => {
    if (result === null || result === undefined) return console.log("RESULT IS NULL OR UNDEFINED", result);
    return admin.database().ref()
    .child("Merchans")
    .child(userId)
    .child(merchanId)
    .update({status: 3});
  })
  .catch(error => {
    return console.log("error", error);
  });

});
```

**My question is**: How to check if the node was removed or not? Because the `.catch()` block is not called when the node does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [@Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64218329/4300670) mentioned, first we have to perform a read operation to check if the node either exists or not.

Then, we can perform the operation we wish. Surely, this extra operation will increase your bill.

Below is code I used for achieving this task.

```
return ref.once('value').then(dataSnapshot => {
    if (dataSnapshot.val() !== null) {
      const promise1 = snapshot.ref.remove();
      const promise2 = dataSnapshot.ref.remove();
      const promise3 = admin.database().ref()
      .child("Merchans").child(userId).child(merchanId).update({status: 3});

      console.log('dataSnapshot exists; removing and updating status', dataSnapshot.val());
      return Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]);
      //return dataSnapshot.ref.remove();
    }
    console.log('dataSnapshot is NULL', dataSnapshot.val());
    return snapshot.ref.remove();
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

A remove operation on Firebase is considered to have succeeded if the end result is that the node isn't there. This means that the operation succeeds when the node doesn't exist when the remove operation is executed.

If you want to be certain that your code actively removes the node, you will have to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#section-transactions), which first reads the node and then sets its new value based on the current value.